# Calling a batch file from python with a string argument containing ^

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to do the following

```
from subprocess import call
call(['C:\\BatchFile.bat', 'SomeText^MoreText'])
```

For some reason the ^ character disappears.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: Try to escape it, i.e: 'SomeText\^MoreText'

Comment: Didn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is from the batch file side.

`^` character is the escaping character in MS-DOS/Windows (like `\` in Linux)

Doubling, tripling, no wait: putting 4 `^` works

```
from subprocess import call
call(['C:\\BatchFile.bat', 'SomeText^^^^MoreText'])
```

`BatchFile.bat` contains:

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

I get

```
SomeText^MoreText
```

Comment: Sure, in 1 minute :)